# What is the phrasal verbs to use when a tube is suddenly not plug anymore?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In a context where a tube connected to a device, suddenly the tube is not connected anymore for some reason. What is the correct phrasal verb to use? "the tube just came off" or "the tube just came out", or something else?

Thank you

Comment: How is the tube connected? Saying "it came off" implies it was *on* something, while saying "it came out" implies it was *in* something.

Comment: I see, the tube is connected on something (the plug is inserted inside the tube). I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It popped out. It fell out. It came loose. It got (AmE) or became disconnected. It slipped off. Depends on the type of tube. If it's a barbed fitting, the tube fell off or got pulled off.

Comment: I don't understand "tube" here? Why not "plug"?

Comment: About plug/tube, plug might not be the correct word. I wanted to mean that the connection point is inserted in the tube if that makes sense.

Comment: I have no idea what "the connection point is inserted in the tube" means. ***Why*** can't you use the word "plug"? What's different about the connection you're asking about? If the two things being connected are, say, a tap and a hosepipe, it's a ***coupling*** or ***connector*** rather than a plug, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tube "popped off" works well (and is descriptive) in a conversation. In a report, you would probably say disconnected, detached, or decoupled. Often people will add the word "became" in front of the verb (that is it "became detached") because without the word "became" it sounds a bit like the tube acted of its own free will.